# Handle the Expression in regex?

Tags: regex

Expression allows only "_” ,“-“ ,".mst" and ".".
And should not allow forward and backward slash(/,).

Anyone can help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're trying to match some kind of a filename, that one should do it:

`(\w|_|-|\.)+\.mst$`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
([_-.]|(\.mst))+
```

This matches any combination of the values you specified. If you want the expression to match only one of them, remove the plus sign at the end. If you have other rules, you should post them.

Comment: No need to escape the dot inside a character class ;-)